# Name for functions that are asymptotically equivalent to their shifted version

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, terminology

I am working on limits and asymptotics and I would like to know (or where to look for) a correct definition of functions that are asymptotically equivalent (for $x\to \infty$) to shifted versions of themselves. That is, at least for sufficiently small $\delta$,
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{f(x+\delta)} = 1,$$
such as $f(x) = x^r$ or $f(x) = \log^r(x)$.
Is there a commonly accepted definition for this? Or is this strictly related to some other definition whom I am not aware of?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken this means that $f(\ln(x))$ is a [slowly varying function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the phrase "at least for sufficiently small $\delta$" isn't necessary.  If the equation holds for some $\delta$, then
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{f(x+2\delta)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)f(x+\delta)}{f(x+\delta)f(x+2\delta)}\\ \qquad =\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{f(x+\delta)}\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x+\delta)}{f(x+2\delta)}=1\cdot1=1,
$$
so it holds for $2\delta$; and so on.  So you can just say that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{f(x)/f(x+\delta)}=1$ for all $\delta$.  And, as noted in a comment, this is is equivalent to saying that
$$
\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(\log u)}{f(\log u + \delta)}=\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(\log u)}{f(\log (e^\delta u))}=1
$$
for all $\delta$, or for all positive $e^{\delta}$; which in turn is the same as saying that $L(u):= f(\log u)$ is a [slowly varying function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function).

Comment: Thanks a lot to you and Martin. I did not know about these definitions by Karamata. Is there a relationship between the functions in OP (that is such functions $f$ such that $f(\log x)$ is slowly varying) and regularly varying functions? I was not able to make use of that other definition instead of using the composition of $(f\circ \log)$, but maybe it is possible?

Comment: Not sure… that may be a good stand-alone question.  The property you give is weaker than needed to guarantee $f$ is slowly varying; but is it strong enough to guarantee $f$ is regularly varying?